# Looking for audio restore plug in

Tags: plug-ins, audio-restoration

Recently (this week) I saw a plug in demo (video) online.
It made low quality music sound like a good recording through some kind of processing with resonant filters or something.. From what I saw the plugin was quite new and revolutionary.

I'm looking for this plugin but can't find it any more. Like I said it was quite new..

The websites that I might have been browsing are:

matrixsynth.com
pro-tools-experts.com
reddit.com ;)
protoolsisawsome.com
designingsound.org
engaget.com

I looked on these websites again but can't find the article / plug...

I'm looking for thisplug in because I have to repair skype sessions :S on short notice :(

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering what plug-in you're talking about, it is Zynaptiq's Unfilter.

Comment: Please close the post/select an answer so that the question goes away from the queue.  It's a problem we've having on SSD.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :) works like a charm...
They  have demo for the people who want to try it out..

http://www.zynaptiq.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's izotope rx2 that you're looking for?